# Ghost CMS Custom Page assets route

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I'm trying to create custom page in Ghost. I named file "news.hbs" for listing all the news items. Also I use webpack. Why while creating new custom page in template all the routes are matching as "news/*"? For example, while webpack generates "news.hbs" file, Ghost requires not an original path "img/header-bg.png", but an "news/img/header-bg.png". How to handle that? In main file "index.hbs" all the paths are valid, without extra folder's names.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the routes.yaml file for the routes to start working. Look at this documentation for more info: https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/handlebars-themes/routing/

Comment: I have done that. My routes.yaml contains: routes: /news/: news. My question is about another thing. Why the news.hbs, which is generated also from news.hbs by webpack, contains "news" prefix in script, link and img tags. Webpack hbs: href="img/news1.jpg", generated hbs: href="news/img/news1.jpg".